# News Feed "More Updates button"

Tags: php, updates

I have been unable to find any results that matches my simple question so here goes..

Iam using PHP and require a "more updates" button(similar to facebook) when viewing the news of my site which retrieves information from the database. Could anyone explain to me how i should go about it? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to elaborate on this. Plus, do you have any code with which you tried something? Now, If I understand correctly, you'll need a jQuery-based script where you would have a "show more" button or text. Have a look at the following link which has a demo link on that page http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

Comment: i would like the more updates button to feature more information retrieved from the database, in this case would mean instead of 5 results, another 5 results would be displayed(this happens when u scroll down in facebook's news feed)

Comment: Then I think what Leornard posted below will work. Have you tried his method? And what I think would work for the loading method is this jQuery method but there's no button, just when you get to the end of the page, it loads new data. Here's the project's link http://dimaxweb.github.io/jquery-paged-scroll/ **and** the demo they have posted http://www.keentour.com/content/North-America (scroll to the end of the page) pretty nice one.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mysql database table (news_table) with the news in the column 'content' and another column 'id' (of type int and primary index + auto increment on).

Make this file get_news.php:

```
<?php

$start = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_REQUEST["start"])));
if (!isset($start))
    $start = 0;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_table WHERE id >= $start LIMIT 15")
if (!$sql || mysql_num_rows($sql)==0)
    exit("There are no more news.");

while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $post['content'];
    echo "</li>"
}


?>
```

And in you main file:

```
<ul class="news">
    <li>Blabla 1</li>
    <li>Blabla 2</li>
</ul>
<button class="load-more" onclick="">Load more...</button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

    var lastPost = 0;
    function loadNews() {
        $('.news').load('get_news.php?start='+lastPost);
        lastPost += 15;
    }

    $('button.load-more').click(loadNews);

    $(function () {
        loadNews();
    });

</script>
```

Good luck!!